# How to add spiderable 1.0.8 to my meteor project?

Tags: meteor

Currently the latest public version of the Spiderable package is 1.0.7 ([atmosphere link](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable)). However on Github the version has been bumped to 1.0.8 ([4 days ago](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/f27bcbb3c4c2209ffda7f0ef0ec79875b4f963d2)).

I need the features from the 1.0.8 update. What's the best way for me to use the 1.0.8 version? I've tried:

```
meteor add spiderable@1.0.8
```

But it didn't work, the output was: `error: no such version spiderable@1.0.8` .

Answer (score 0):

This version of spiderable has not yet been published by MDG. This is why it says `no such version`.

While a package is being developed the version may be higher than the version available for use. When it has been tested its usually published along the next meteor version.

There may still be more changes to the package until its published.

If you want to use the package anyway you can copy the `spiderable` directory from github into a `packages/spiderable` directory. This may not work with certain dependency errors depending on whether another package using spiderable is required.

The second is to use the github version of meteor. Which is to clone the meteor project using `git clone https://github.com/meteor/meteor` then use the `meteor` binary (with the full absolute path) to run your project instead of `meteor` on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know the answer to my question, i.e. what's the best way to install the version 1.0.8 anyway? Can I somehow set the github repository as the source for this package?

Comment: @MauricioTarre Ive updated my answer with somethng that can help you do this

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've followed your advice (the first one). I'm using no packages which declare spiderable as dependency (there is no spiderable in my .meteor/versions). I've cloned the github repository, copied packages/spiderable into my packages directory, tried adding it with `meteor add spiderable` and still got error: `error: No version of spiderable satisfies all constraints: @=1.0.8, @=1.0.7`

Comment: @MauricioTarre You can only do one, not both. If you clone the github repo delete the spiderable package. If you need to add or remove a package or run the project use the binary in the cloned git directory not `meteor` as I mentioned. As with before it may be worth waiting for the package to be published as in this state it is not yet final. This error is expected if you don't use the dev build/git build of meteor correctly.

Comment: I did only one, I've followed your first advice. I've cloned the git repository and copied just the spiderable package into my project's packages directory.

Comment: Did you ever solve the "No version satisfies all constraints" error?